# How to find the number of video games released triannually?

Tags: mysql, function, intervals

Lets say i have a table **videogames** and I want to find the number of games released in
in intervals of 3 years starting from year 1997.

**videogames**

| videogameid | title | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GoldenEye 007 | 1997 |
| 2 | Tomb Raider II | 1997 |
| 3 | Half-Life | 1998 |
| 4 | The Sims | 2000 |
| 5 | GTA (III) | 2001 |
| 6 | Kingdom Hearts | 2003 |
| 7 | World Of Warcraft | 2004 |
| 8 | ES4: Oblivion | 2006 |
| 9 | L.A. Noire | 2011 |
| 10 | Far Cry 3 | 2012 |
| 11 | Diablo III | 2012 |

From the table, the expected output should be Year (1997-1999) = 3, Year (2000-2002) = 2,
Year(2003 - 2005) = 2, Year(2006-2008) = 1, Year (2009 - 2011 ) = 1 and Year (2012-2014)= 2

This is my attempt at solving the code:

```
SELECT COUNT(videogameid) AS number_of_videogames
FROM videogames 
WHERE INTERVAL(1997,2,2,2,2,2,2)
GROUP BY YEAR;
```

For some reason, I got returned back more than 100 ++ rows of answers when they should only be 6 rows for each interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2022-03-06**

It seems strange to list the totals with no reference year numbers :-) but if that's all you want, try:

```
WITH recursive ReleaseYears AS (
  -- build list of years 
  SELECT MIN(`year`) AS YearNum
  FROM   VideoGames
  UNION ALL
  SELECT YearNum + 1
  FROM   ReleaseYears
  WHERE  YearNum <= ( SELECT MAX(`year`) + 2 FROM VideoGames) 
)
SELECT COUNT(vg.videogameid) AS Num
FROM   ( -- group year numbers in groups of 3 
         SELECT FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT YearNum)) -1) / 3) + 1 AS YearGroup
               , YearNum
         FROM   ReleaseYears
       ) y LEFT JOIN VideoGames vg ON y.YearNum = vg.`year`
GROUP BY YearGroup       
HAVING COUNT(vg.videogameid) > 0
```

**Results:**

> ```
> | Num |
> | --: |
> |   3 |
> |   2 |
> |   2 |
> |   1 |
> |   1 |
> ```

---

**Original Answer**

If you want to display the year in format "(min-max)":

```
WITH recursive ReleaseYears AS (
  SELECT MIN(`year`) AS YearNum
  FROM   VideoGames
  UNION ALL
  SELECT YearNum + 1
  FROM   ReleaseYears
  WHERE  YearNum <= ( SELECT MAX(`year`) + 2 FROM VideoGames) 
)
SELECT YearGroup
       , CONCAT_WS('-', MIN(YearNum), MAX(YearNum)) AS YearRange
       , COUNT(vg.videogameid) AS Num
FROM   (
         SELECT FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT YearNum)) -1) / 3) + 1 AS YearGroup
               , YearNum
         FROM   ReleaseYears
       ) y LEFT JOIN VideoGames vg ON y.YearNum = vg.`year`
GROUP BY YearGroup       
HAVING COUNT(vg.videogameid) > 0
;
```

**Results:**

> ```
> YearGroup | YearRange | Num
> --------: | :-------- | --:
>         1 | 1997-1999 |   3
>         2 | 2000-2002 |   2
>         3 | 2003-2005 |   2
>         4 | 2006-2008 |   1
>         5 | 2009-2011 |   1
>         6 | 2012-2014 |   2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ca04879e4a8d16fd969adfe8e257557)*

Comment: Hello, I am just interested in the foundation of the code.  As I just want to know the number of movies and I don't care about displaying the interval of years so is it possible to show one that has the num column only without the year group and year range/list . With that said thank you for the help much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way you could change the code so that it becomes decades instead of trianually ?

Comment: The formula to calculate that is `((RowNum - 1) / {YearsToGroup}) + 1`.  Just change the number **3** to **10** in this sql: `FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT YearNum)) -1) / 3)`

Comment: I dont not see alias RowNum and YearsToGroup in the code though ?

Comment: That's a plain english explanation of what this sql does: `FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT YearNum)) -1) / 3)`.   Currently, YearsToGroup = 3. Just change the number 3 to a 10.

Comment: Much appreciated. Cheers. Thank you

Comment: Btw is there a way, I could start with a certain year instead of min year like stated in 
`SELECT MIN(`year`) AS YearNum`  Like for example, I start with 2005-2014, 2015-2024, 2025-2034

Comment: Yes, the CTE can generate whatever year range you want https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=583a411dd50846e703d2fc01f050bc07

Answer (score 0):

About the simplest I think you can get is to use a recursive CTE to generate your years and simply outer-join this to your source data and group into 3 like so:

```
with recursive n as (
    select Min(year) yn, Ceiling((max(year)-Min(year))/3.0)*3 + min(year) maxyear, Min(year) minyear 
    from t
    union all
    select yn + 1, maxyear, minyear
    from n
    where yn < maxyear
)
select Min(yn) FromYear, Max(yn) toYear, Count(year) qty
from n
left join t on t.year=yn
group by floor((yn - minyear) /3);
```

[Demo DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd4ceaad0c0e6de8f276df1a27f06334)

Comment: have you tried using the INTERVAL() command ?